# How to fill drop down from sql database

Tags: php, html, database

I have seen other question similar but can't seem to find an answer. I am using the code below to generate a drop-down box containing the cites in a 'Hostel' table. A drop-down box is made however there is nothing written into it. Below is my code.

```
<?php

$conn= new mysqli('localhost','username','password','database')
or die ('Cannot connect to db');

$result = $conn->query("select city from Hostel");

echo "<html>";
echo "<body>";
echo "<select city='city'>";

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $city = $row['city'];
    echo '<option value="'.$city.'"></option>';
}

echo "</select>";
echo "</body>";
echo "</html>";
?>
```

Comment: Check the [HTML documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option) before asking a question. SO is not a replaceent for a bit of personal research OR looking at the provided Documentation

Comment: Your `<option>` does not have any content. `<option>$city</option>`.

Answer (score 2):

You're populating the *value* of the `<option>` (which is hidden by the browser, and used only when sending the selected option's value back to the server when the form to which the `<select>` belongs is submitted), but not its visible *content*.

As per the usual convention in HTML, the visible content belongs between the opening and closing tags of the `<option>`.

e.g.

```
echo '<option value="'.$city.'">'.$city.'</option>';
```

Documentation and examples: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option